# About custom email validation in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I tried to write my own custom auth form in meteor. for the email validation part, the system send out an email with the route and token appended on it. However, I want to get the token in the validation page, so I tired the following

```
Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink(function(token, done) {
  console.log("hello");
  Session.set(verifyEmailToken, token); 
  doneCallback = done; 
});
Template.emailVerified.onCreated(function(){
  console.log(Session.get(verifyEmailToken));
  Accounts.verifyEmail(Session.get(verifyEmailToken),function(err){
    if(err){
      Session.set(ERROR_KEY,err.reason);
    }else{
      Session.set(SUCESS_KEY,"Your email has been verified, thank you!");
      if (doneCallback) {
           doneCallback();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

But the Accounts.onEmailVerificationLink method doesn't seem like have been invoked. Did I miss something there? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Server code:

```
Accounts.urls.verifyEmail = function(token) {
    return Meteor.absoluteUrl('verify/' + token);
};
```

Common/Both Router:

```
AccountController = RouteController.extend({
    verifyEmail: function() {
        Accounts.verifyEmail(this.params.token, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                // error
            } else {
                //  
            }
        });
    }
});




Router.map(function() {
    return this.route('verifyEmail', {
        controller: 'AccountController',
        path: '/verify/:token',
        action: 'verifyEmail'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks,bya. Is there a way to do it template level? I tried to minimize the router logic.